# How can I plot an interactive 3d scatterplot from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

Pandas provides builtin plotting functionality for `DataFrame`s with several plotting backend engines (`matplotlib`, etc.). Id like to plot an interactive 3D scatterplot directly from a dataframe via `df.plot()` but came up with non-interactive plots only. I'm thinking of something I get when e.g. [`plotly`](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/). I'd prefer a solution which is independent of exploratory data analysis IDE setup dependencies (e.g. `ipywidget` when using JupyterLab). How can I plot interactive 3D scatter plots via `df.plot()`?

Answer (score 1):

plotly is the way to go...use scatter3d

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=df['A'],
    y=df['B'],
    z=df['C'],

    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=5,
        color=c,              
        colorscale='Viridis',   
    ),
    name= 'test',

    # list comprehension to add text on hover
    text= [f"A: {a}<br>B: {b}<br>C: {c}" for a,b,c in list(zip(df['A'], df['B'], df['C']))],
    # if you do not want to display x,y,z
    hoverinfo='text'
)


layout = dict(title = 'TEST',)

data = [trace]
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

py.offline.plot(fig, filename = 'Test.html')
```

Comment: I know how to use plotly. But I want to create an interactive plot directly from a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame.plot()`. And as far as I know plotly is not supported as pandas plotting backend engine.

Comment: It is not possible yet...https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2005

Answer (score 0):

Holding to the `df.plot()` approach there is an `df.iplot()` with [Cufflinks and Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/cufflinks/).

Comment: I already used cufflinks. However I'd prefer a solution which does not depend on `ipywidget`. It's anoying if you get no output and have to care about jupyterlab setup if you want a `hvplot` like solution (whose interactive plots work with JupyterLab out of the box).